# How to use post-receive hook after git push to gitolite server?

Tags: git, hook, gitolite, git-post-receive

I tried to use post-receive hook to make a new build on Jenkins after every push to the gitolite server, BUT it doesn't work automatically after push and I need to execute post-receive file manually by terminal to run it and make a build on Jenkins.

AFAIK, all I need is to:

1. Modify the post-receive file on server to make what I want "make a new build in Jenkins".
2. Push code to the gitolite server by command "git push".

and the post-receive hook will execute automatically after push process, Am I right ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order for people to help with this, you will most likely have to include your current `post-receive` hook as part of your question.

Comment: it is not the problem ..consider it has only an echo expression.The problem is it doesn't execute automatically after push, and I must execute it manually in terminal

Comment: Are you modifying the `gitolite-admin` hooks instead of the hooks in the `repositories` directory?

Comment: I modify the hooks in project directory repository on server.not the gitolite-admin.

Comment: There's still not enough information in your question, I'm afraid.  How exactly are you running the hook manually?  (e.g. if you're running it as `sh post-receive`, the problem might be that the script isn't executable or the shebang line is wrong or missing - this is another reason why I asked you to post the contents of the hook.)  Another question is exactly what is the path of the post-receive file?  Do you see any errors preceded by `remote:` when you do a `git push`?

Comment: Thanks melee , u lead me to the right direction.. I was modifying the wrong file, I should modify the gitolite-admin hook... Thanks all for your time.

Comment: @se7s Please add your solution as an answer so it can be voted up. It will also be easier for visitors of this page to see the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Make shure that the file has the execute bit set and that it belongs to the gitolite user. Also make shure to call each command from there with its full path as PATH is limited while executing the hook.